# @RabbitListener Not receiving messages from queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using @RabbitListner annotation to recieve messages from a RabbitMq queue.

Although I have done all steps required to do this (i.e. Add @EnableRabbit annotation in my config class) and declare SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory as a bean , still my method is not recieving messages from the queue . Can anybody suggest what I am missing :

I am using Spring Boot to launch my application

My launch class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableRabbit
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan("persistence.mysql.domain")
@EnableJpaRepositories("persistence.mysql.dao")
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApiAuthenticationFilter.class),@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = ApiVersionValidationFilter.class)},basePackages = {"common", "mqclient","apache", "dispatcher" })
public class Application {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final SpringApplicationBuilder appBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
            Application.class);
    appBuilder.application().setWebEnvironment(false);
    appBuilder.profiles("common", "common_mysql_db", "common_rabbitmq")
            .run(args);
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}


}
```

Here is my Bean to define  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory inside a component class

```
@Component(value = "inputQueueManager")
public class InputQueueManagerImpl extends AbstractQueueManagerImpl {
```

..///..

```
 @Bean(name = "inputListenerContainerFactory")
 public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory()     

 {
 SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new    
 SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
 factory.setConnectionFactory(this.rabbitConnectionFactory);
 factory.setConcurrentConsumers(Integer.parseInt(this.concurrentConsumers));


factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(Integer.parseInt(this.maxConcurrentConsumers));
factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
return factory;
```

}
}

And finally my Listener  inside another Controller component

```
@Controller
public class RabbitListner{
 @RabbitListener(queues = "Storm1", containerFactory = "inputListenerContainerFactory")
 @Override
 public void processMessage(QueueMessage message) {
    String topic = message.getTopic();
    String payload = message.getPayload();
    dispatcher.bean.EventBean eventBean = new dispatcher.bean.EventBean();
    System.out.println("Data read from the queue");
```

Unfortunately , I am sending the messages to the queue but the code inside processMessage is not getting executed ever.

I am not sure what is the problem here . Can anybody help ??

Comment: I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and look at the logs; you should see the beans being wired up and the container starting. If you can't figure it out, post the log someplace (e.g. pastebin).

Comment: I see that my bean is getting initialized and loaded  in the Spring ApplicationContext . But still I dont see the processMessage code invoked . One question , do we need to declare any custom java method  to recieve message or any java method can do the job . What I mean is I have declared public void processMessage(QueueMessage message) . Should QueueMessage be implementing some SpringAMQP interface?

Comment: Any method will do the job as long as the message can be converted to the parameter type; exactly what is `QueueMessage`? Is it something that can be decoded from JSON (since that's the converter you provide). What is sending the message? The JSON message converter, by default, needs hints to know what to convert the JSON to. If those headers are not present you will need to customize its `ClassMapper`. The DEBUG logging will show container activity once per second (seeing if there is a message available).

Comment: QueueMessage is a custom javaObject with 2 attributes topic and payload . Also , if I use custom listener then also I am getting Message Conversion Exception . Unfortunately , I couldnt find much documentation for Customizing classMapper . While debugging I could see classMapper set as null and
 if (getClassMapper() == null) {
      JavaType targetJavaType = getJavaTypeMapper()
        .toJavaType(message.getMessageProperties());

When above is invoked I get the exception . If possible can u help how to use ClassMapper . Even better if u can document it in SPRING Amqp documentaion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Json message converter requires hints in the message properties as to what type of object to create.

If your producer does not set those properties, it won't be able to do the conversion without some help.

You can inject a `ClassMapper` into the converter.

The framework provides a `DefaultClassMapper` which can be customized - either to look at a different message property than the default `__TypeId__` property.

If you always want to convert the json to the same object, you can simply set the default type:

```
DefaultClassMapper classMapper = newDefaultClassMapper();
classMapper.setDefaultType(QueueMessage.class);
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
converter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
```

The [documentation already shows how to configure this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#json-message-converter).

Comment: Thanks Gary . One thing though , this will only work when we use the same object to send and receive from the queue and set same ClassMapper at converter end for both publisher and consumer .  Ideally , publisher will send any object to broker in which case I believe this wont work. I am looking for making it a generic way .

Comment: The `DefaultClassMapper` (outbound) inserts a `__TypeId__` property in the message which is used inbound to determine the class to instantiate. If you want to customize the property name you can subclass the default mapper and override `getClassIdFieldName()`. Or, you can write a completely custom `ClassMapper` to do whatever you want.